# Ruby bug with fresh install (no implicit conversion of nil into String)

Tags: ruby

I updated Ruby. When I request Ruby version in CLI, it works, but when I request for the Gem version, it returns the following error:

> C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:90:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

The error is found on a portable version on Windows, as well as on an installed version.

I don't know what to do to run a working version of Ruby. Does anyone already got this bug or have a clue to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the exact error message "no implicit conversion of nil into String", I finally found a working solution (may not be the best).

I replace the line 90:

> SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE = File.join SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH, 'gemrc'

With:

> SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE = File.join SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH.to_s, 'gemrc'

Comment: This is no way the solution, `SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH` is nil in your case, so `SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH.to_s` will be an empty string. so the join result is nothing but `gemrc`, it could be anywhere.

Comment: I can't do it on macOS Catalina. It says: `The file “config_file.rb” is on a read-only volume and cannot be unlocked`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow set the environment variable `SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH`

Here's line `90` of `rubygems/config_file.rb`:

```
SYSTEM_WIDE_CONFIG_FILE = File.join SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH, 'gemrc'
```

That fails when `SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH` is nil.

Comment: `SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH` is not an environment variable, it's defined in lines 61 through 86 of `rubygems/config_file.rb`

Comment: What should be the correct value for SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH then? As said SteveTurczyn, I'm not sure this have to be an environment variable (as for the 1.8.7 portable version, everything was OK).

Comment: the SYSTEM_CONFIG_PATH comes from Etc.sysconfdir see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html#method-c-sysconfdir and the value comes from the prefix used when ruby was compiled on that machine.  I'd try a reinstall of ruby as a first step.